# Chrome not add my custom search_provider on extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension by adding my own search engine. I am the owner of all the domain already verified in Google Search Console. When I test on Development in Chrome, it doesn't override the search provider and it doesn't return any errors.

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
"homepage": "https://__MSG_domainExt__",
"search_provider": {
  "name": "__MSG_searchExt__",
  "search_url": "https://__MSG_domainExt__/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q={searchTerms}&gsc.sort=",
  "favicon_url": "https://__MSG_domainExt__/favicon.ico",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "is_default": true
},
"startup_pages": [ "https://__MSG_domainExt__" ]
```

},

Comment: Might be a bug. Try putting the actual URL in manifest.json for search_url and favicon_url and see if it helps.

Comment: I do it before and bot working too

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) says it's available only in Windows and Mac, not in Linux.

Comment: I use Windows...